# Wired LAN is connected to computer but internet is not working

Tags: networking, internet, lan

I'm using a Ubuntu live USB to install something to another drive but I can't get the internet to work. I've tried connecting a wired LAN, wifi, my phone as a hotspot but it never works. Oftentimes, it doesn't even connect to the LAN even though it is plugged in. And I can confirm the LAN does work with my 2010 MBP. And when it does detect the LAN, the internet never works. How can I fix this? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: If you connect to the LAN it could be a DHCP issue..
type  *ifconfig* to check your ubuntu network settings.
When you are connected can you ping your router or google?
 *ping 8.8.8.8*

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I set IPs to DHCP on the daily:

Get and install vim (if needed):

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Open to edit the network interfaces file:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Make changes to the network interface for DHCP not static (note: I referenced My Ubuntu Server 16 LTSs Ethernet port named enp2s0. Be aware that I've also seen p2p1, as well as the classic eth0, your machine may have labeled your Ethernet port slightly differently):

```
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

Then save the changes with the ESC Key and type:

```
:wq
```

Then restart the service as you normally do or as I would do:

```
sudo ifdown enp2s0
```

wait

```
sudo ifup enp2s0
```

Now check your ifconfig and you should now see the static IP
ifconfig

Good luck and Enjoy!

If that doesn't work, try shutting all network interfaces off and back on with `sudo ifdown -a` and `sudo ifup -a`

Comment: Recommending a new person to vim isnt fun during an issue